# Spark/Scala - Rename the Columns Produced by List

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to rename the `_1`, `_2` to meaningful column names in Spark/Scala?

```
root
   |-- aaa: string (nullable = true)
   |-- bbb: array (nullable = true)
   |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
   |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
   |    |    |-- _2: long (nullable = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a case class and convert tuples into case class. this way you can have named tuple.

```
case class person(name:String,age:Int)
 val personRdd=rdd.map(_.split(<delimeter>)).map(x => person(x._1,x._2))
```

now you can access personRdd tuple values as

```
personRdd.map(p => (p.name+":"+p.age))
```